# Who cook the soup? Confusion

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

[我煮汤 = I cook soup, this has confused who cook the soup..can you tell me grammer points how not to confuse with subject and object in this scenario:]

I am translating this sentence,

他第一次为我煮汤，是在妈妈离家的那一天

“he first time do I cook soup.” My literal translation

But actual translation is “he made soup for me for the first time ....”

Text as below for context:

爸爸有一个星期没有来送汤了。真搞不懂他，已经退休了，又没事做，煮点汤有什么难的？好不容易等到他给我送汤，却不是熬出来的“好东西”。有时连肉块都省了，和以前那醇厚的味道比起来，真是天渊之别！我已经喝惯了爸爸煮的汤。他第一次为我煮汤，是在妈妈离家的那一天。我当时不知道妈妈为何要离家出走，后来才明白她是认为爸爸没出息。为什么她这么残忍，她可以不要爸爸，怎么可以不要我呢？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You translated '为我' as 'do I'

> 他第一次[为我]煮汤

> he the first time [do I] cook soup

Google Translate:

> 为 --> for

> 为我 --> for me

Your confusion started with you didn't have the accurate translation of '为我'

- [他][第一次][为我][煮汤]
- [he][the first time][for me][cook soup]

Although the placement of the subject and object in the Chinese sentence above is different from English grammar, it is easily understandable and be rearranged in English grammar

> The first time he cooks soup for me

I guess you translated '为我' as 'do I' because '为' also contains the meaning of 'as; be; is'.

The general rule is when '为' means 'being' it cannot be followed by a verb phrase like 'cook soup'.

- 为 in [为 + noun + verb phrase] always means 'for'.  E.g. '为我死' = 'die for me'
- 为 in [noun 1 + 为 + noun 2] always means 'as/ being/ is'. E.g. '水为财' = 'water is wealth'

Answer (score 1):

1. The fundamental sentence is `他煮湯` (he cooks soup). The subject is `他` and the object is `湯`, or the thing that is cooked.
2. You may consider `第一次` (the first time) and `為我` (for me) as adverbial phrases. They describe how the soup was cooked by Father.
3. `為+sb`, `替+sb`, and `幫+sb` indicate the action is done on behalf of someone. They behave like `給+sb`. E.g.:

   - `我為你打掃了房間` I cleaned the room for you.
   - `他替我做功課` He does homework for me.
   - `我幫她買了雞蛋` I bought eggs for her.